# Change body onLoad on img click

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events

I have a page that has a tag `<body onload="setInterval('window.location.reload()', 60000);">` that causes the page to refresh every 1 minute.

I want to make a button (<kbd>PAUSE</kbd>) that, when clicked, cancels the refresh.

I have tried the following, but it does not work:

```
window.onload= function () {};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [clearInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp)

In your script:

```
var pid=false;
function clear()
{
   clearInterval(pid);
   pid=false;
}
function resume()
{
   if(!pid)
     pid=setInterval('window.location.reload()', 60000); 
}
```

In the body

```
<body onload="pid=setInterval('window.location.reload()', 60000);">....
<button onclick="clear()">Pause</button>
<button onclick="resume()">Resume</button>....
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call `clearInterval()` like this

```
id = setInterval('func', time);
<button onlcick="clearInterval(id)">Pause</button>
```

`clearInterval()` is a method in the `window` object which CLEARS your `setInterval()`

[Here's a link](http://bit.ly/MiX2Qd) with more information

Answer (score 1):

It's better if you put your scripts in a function so that you can call it from other places too.

Like this...

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var intervalRef;   
        function ResumeRefresh(interval){
            intervalRef = setInterval('window.location.reload()', interval);
        }
        function StopRefresh(){
            intervalRef=window.clearInterval(intervalRef);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="ResumeRefresh(60000);">
    <input type="button" val="Stop Refreshing" onclick="StopRefresh();"></input>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need something like this:

```
<script>
var reloadInterval;
var run = true;
function setMyInterval()
{
   reloadInterval = setInterval('window.location.reload()', 60000);
}
function Pause()
{
   if(run)
   {
      clearInterval(reloadInterval);
   }
   else 
   {
      reloadInterval = setInterval('window.location.reload()', 60000);
   }
}
</script>
```

html:

```
<body onload = 'setMyInterval()'>
<button onlcick="Pause()">Pause / Play</button>
```